# script command from socat - /dev/ttyUSB0

Tags: raspberry-pi, modem, ttyusb, huawei

A usb-modem connected to my Raspberry PI with Raspian lite.

I've finally found a way to make it connect by issuing these two steps:

```
sudo socat - /dev/ttyUSB1
```

and from within Socat I just write:

```
AT^NDISDUP=1,1,"4g.tele2.se"
```

...to make my usb-modem connect.

How can I now send this command using a shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Bash, you can use the here-string syntax:

```
sudo socat - /dev/ttyUSB1 <<< 'AT^NDISDUP=1,1,"4g.tele2.se"'
```

Else, with a regular (POSIX) `sh`, use the here-document syntax:

```
sudo socat - /dev/ttyUSB1 << EOF
AT^NDISDUP=1,1,"4g.tele2.se"
EOF
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! I tried echo 'statement' | socat - /dev/ttyUSB1 but then it broke the statement somehow..

Comment: `echo | socat`  should equally work. What you missed is probably `sudo`. NOT `sudo echo | socat` but `echo ... | sudo socat` (echo doesn't need sudo to work, but socat does). `echo` has several downsides, so using `printf` instead is preferable. The advantage of the here-document syntax above is that you can easily add other AT commands and keep everything legible. With `<<- EOF` instead of `<< EOF` you can even indent the content.